# What's the curved part called on a boning knife, near the heel? And what is it for?

Tags: knives, bones

I was watching [this instruction](https://youtu.be/bh2q-7GiQ6A?si=T06EJAgMWa2xaI2Z&t=23) on deboning a chicken thigh. If I hear it correctly she says there's a "divot". I think she uses the word "divot" to describe the curve of the knife as a dent, but I don't think the word is commonly used this way. So what is that part called technically? I know choil is the part of a kitchen knife near the heel that is unsharpened.

Also how does one use it exactly? I don't have a boning knife and I've been deboning chicken occasionally. And I wonder if I should get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curved part near the heel of a boning knife is called the "belly," and it is designed to facilitate rocking motions for more precise and controlled cutting, especially when working with meat and bones.